# Leaflet : Show only elements on screen

Tags: leaflet

I have a very huge geoson and when it is loaded, the map is very slow.

I would like to display on the map only elements related to the visible screen (compatible with move and zoom).

There is the code :

```
var geojsonLayerAerien = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("/json/data.json",
        {
            style: {
                weight: 3,
                color: "#5588EE",
                opacity: 0.5,
                fillColor: "#B0DE5C",
                fillOpacity: 0.3
            },
            onEachFeature: onEachFeature
        }
    );

var overlayMaps = {
            "Réseau Aérien": geojsonLayerAerien
        };

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMaps, null, { collapsed: true }).addTo(map);
```

Can you help me to achieve the code or give me some tips?
Thank you

Comment: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.VectorGrid

Answer (score 0):

Try to filter the data with php or something else, before you load the data, so the calculation is on server side.

But if you want on client side, you can check if the latlngs of the object is in the map bounds:

```
var bbox = mymap.getBounds().pad(0.3); //Expand bounds 10%
var rect = L.rectangle(bbox, {fillColor: '#f00'}).addTo(mymap); //Only for showing the loading area

function bboxFilter(feature) {
  if (feature.geometry.type === "Point"){
        var latlng = L.latLng(feature.geometry.coordinates[1],feature.geometry.coordinates[0]);
        if(bbox.contains(latlng)){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
  }else{
        var polylatlng = new L.Polyline([]);
        var coords = feature.geometry.coordinates;
      coords[0].forEach(function(coord){
        var lat = coord[1];
        var lng = coord[0];
        polylatlng.addLatLng(L.latLng([lat,lng]));
      });

        if(bbox.contains(polylatlng.getLatLngs())){
        polylatlng.removeFrom(mymap);
        return true;
        }else{
        polylatlng.removeFrom(mymap);
        return false;
         }
  }
}


var geojson = L.geoJSON(json,{filter: bboxFilter}).addTo(mymap);

mymap.on('moveend',reloadData);
function reloadData(){
    bbox = mymap.getBounds().pad(0.3); //Expand bounds 10%
    geojson.clearLayers();
  geojson = L.geoJSON(json,{filter: bboxFilter}).addTo(mymap);
  rect.setBounds(bbox);
}
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/falkedesign/b2st3m9u/

PS:change `bbox = mymap.getBounds().pad(0.3);` to `bbox = mymap.getBounds().pad(-0.1);` to see the effect